# What is the season when the title was decided with the most races remaining?

Tags: formula-1

In 2021, the F1 title was decided on the final race of the season, at Abu Dhabi. In 2022, it's possible for Max Verstappen to win the title at the Singapore GP and still have 5 races left. Would this be the most races left where the title is already decided? Has the title ever been decided earlier than this?

Answer (score 2):

The record for this was set in 2002, when Michael Schumacher won the championship after 11 races of a 17-race season. There were therefore **6** races that took place after Schumacher had already won the title.